# I want to integrate the following expression:

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to integrate the following expression:
$$\int_0^t v_{xx\tau}(x,\tau) d\tau$$

Why I can not get the following ?

$$v_{xx}(x,t)-v_{xx}(x,0)$$

or how to suppose that $v_{xx\tau}$ is continuous in Mathematica and how to get my desire in the question?

```
Integrate[D[v[x, t0], {x, 2}, t0], {t0, 0, t}]//FullSimplify
```

Comment: Because this is not generally true. It holds only if $v_{xx\tau}$ is continuous on $[0,t]$.

Comment: You are right. In Mathematica, how to suppose that v_{xx/Tau} is continuous and how to get my desire in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to use [`DSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolveValue):

```
DSolveValue[
    {g'[t0] == D[v[x,t0], {x,2}, t0], g[0] == 0},
    g[t],
    t0
] //InputForm
```

> -Derivative[2, 0][v][x, 0] + Derivative[2, 0][v][x, t]

Answer (score 0):

Note that Mathematica will do the indefinite integral:

```
vxx[x_, t_] = Integrate[D[v[x, t], {x, 2}, t], t]
(*Derivative[2, 0][v][x, t]*)
```

Then if you know the function is continuous, you can apply your limits.

```
vxx[x, t0] - vxx[x, 0]
(*Derivative[2, 0][v][x, t0] - Derivative[2, 0][v][x, 0]*)
```

Mathematica 8 will do what you want directly.